# Can we pre-fill the username field for the Amazon Cognito login screen?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html#get-login).

I want to prefill the username (email) field when the user is landing on the  Cognito login screen.

Maybe with the help of query parameters, we can do it. But there is no parameter for it in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html#get-login).

Need a solution for it. We can not use the default email feature as I want to make it dynamic.

I have tried with the login_hint parameter but it didn't worked.